# Getting API Response header as POJO using retrofit in android

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit for API requests. In my application i get data as response in both header and body. As we all know "body" we can convert as POJO by using some libraries using Gson or Jackson etc, **In the similar way is there anyway we can get headers as POJO? Or suggest the best approach to make both header and body in one POJO class.**

NOTE: IN both header and body i get the data as Json format

Below is the code i am using to send request.

```
override fun login(request: LoginModel.Request) {

    val call: Call<LoginModel.Response> = apiService.login(request)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginModel.Response> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginModel.Response>, response: Response<LoginModel.Response>) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "login success")
            if (response != null) {
                val status = response.code()
                var headers =   response.headers();
                var names =  headers.names();

                for (name:String in names ) {
                    Log.d("Testing","name:"+name+" value:"+headers.get(name))
                }

                if (response.body() != null) {
                    var loginResponse: LoginModel.Response = response.body() as LoginModel.Response;

                        if (status == 200) {
                            responseCallback?.onSuccess(loginResponse)
                        } else {
                            responseCallback?.onFailure(loginResponse)
                        }

                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginModel.Response>, t: Throwable) {
            responseCallback?.onFailure("Something went wrong while login")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get header like this:

```
Headers headers=response.headers();
```

Headers.class definination:

/**
 * The header fields of a single HTTP message. Values are uninterpreted strings;
 *
 *

This class tracks header values line-by-line. A field with multiple comma- separated values on
 * the same line will be treated as a field with a single value by this class. It is the caller's
 * responsibility to detect and split on commas if their field permits multiple values. This
 * simplifies use of single-valued fields whose values routinely contain commas, such as cookies or
 * dates.
 *
 *

This class trims whitespace from values. It never returns values with leading or trailing
 * whitespace.
 *
 *

Instances of this class are immutable.
 */

To get values from multiple headers:

```
headers.values("Set-Cookie")
```

For the same name of headers:

```
List<String> cookieList = headers.toMultimap().get("set-cookie")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. In my code i am able to get headers. I want to convert those headers into POJO. Is there any solution?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.